# Material UI: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: null

Tags: webpack, material-ui, babeljs

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: null. Check the render method of TransitionGroup.`

To be very specific, this issue only occurs when I use material-ui and import any of it's component. I can't provide specific steps to reproduce this as it seems to be a webpack config or a babel config and this is a very generic one. Also, there are bunch of others who experienced this issue already and I've tried many solutions with no success. That's why I decided that maybe the stack overflow community can shed some light.

So first, I'm 100% accurate that the issue is using @material-ui. In my project I tried importing just a `Button` like so

`import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'`

And using it like:

```
<Button
        onClick={()=>{}}
        size='small'
        variant='outlined'
        color='secondary'
        className='primary-button'>
 This is a Button
</Button>
```

Also I already tried different imports like `import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'`. So 1st level and 2nd level imports. 3rd level is already not Ok. With NO success! Just a note, removing the `Button` will work 100%. So I'm guessing that this could be a config issue either from babel or webpack. So I played around and research a lot, But no success still!

Here is my current `webpack.config`

```
/**
 * COMMON WEBPACK CONFIGURATION
 */

const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const LoadableWebpackPlugin = require('@loadable/webpack-plugin')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')

module.exports = options => (merge.smart({
  bail: true,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader',
            options: {
              // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
              limit: 10 * 1024,
              noquotes: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
              limit: 10 * 1024
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              mozjpeg: {
                enabled: false
                // NOTE: mozjpeg is disabled as it causes errors in some Linux environments
                // Try enabling it in your environment by switching the config to:
                // enabled: true,
                // progressive: true,
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false
              },
              optipng: {
                optimizationLevel: 7
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: '65-90',
                speed: 4
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['build'], {
      root: process.cwd(),
      verbose: true,
      dry: false
    }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new LoadableWebpackPlugin({ writeToDisk: true })
  ],
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(process.cwd(), 'sass'),
      path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules'),
      path.join(process.cwd(), 'src')
    ],
    extensions: ['.json', '.js']
  },
  target: 'web' // Make web variables accessible to webpack, e.g. window
}, options))
```

And here is my current `babel.config.js`

```
function isWebTarget(caller) {
  return Boolean(caller && caller.target === 'web')
}

module.exports = (api) => {
  const web = api.caller(isWebTarget)
  return {
    presets: [
      [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          loose: true,
          targets: !web ? { node: 'current' } : {
            esmodules: true
          },
          modules: 'commonjs'
        }
      ],
      '@babel/preset-react'
    ],
    plugins: [
      '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind',
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
      ['babel-plugin-import', {
        libraryName: '@material-ui/core'
      }, 'core'],
      ['babel-plugin-import', {
        libraryName: '@material-ui/icons'
      }, 'icons'],
      [
        'transform-imports',
        {
          '@material-ui/core': {
            // Use "transform: '@material-ui/core/${member}'," if your bundler does not support ES modules
            'transform': '@material-ui/core/${member}',
            'preventFullImport': true
          },
          '@material-ui/icons': {
            // Use "transform: '@material-ui/icons/${member}'," if your bundler does not support ES modules
            'transform': '@material-ui/icons/${member}',
            'preventFullImport': true
          }
        }
      ],
      '@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator',
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
      '@loadable/babel-plugin',
      web && 'react-hot-loader/babel'
    ].filter(Boolean)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the whole code of the component that causes the error? It's an error from react so I have a feeling you might not be returning correctly from the render function

Comment: Hi @IlanKhirin, Thank you for the response, as I mentioned. No problem with the parent component, render works perfectly as long as I don't include the material-ui `Button`. Actually the parent component is fairly simple. It's just a `<div>` with the `Button` in it.

Comment: I import it like this: import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'; Have you tried deleting your node modules and re-running npm install? It's either that or you didn't use it correctly in your code. If it doesn't help I would like to see the code of the component which causes the problem and your package.json

Comment: Yes- It tried deleting the node_modules multiple times. I also tried `import { Button } from '@material-ui/core`. Nothing works- And by the way- I tried it on create-react-app and it does work from their. My component is very simple, here: https://putcode.com/Qk5aatXahx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this on `webpack.config`

So for other's that might encounter the same issue, in my `webpack.config`

From:

```
 resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(process.cwd(), 'sass'),
      path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules'),
      path.join(process.cwd(), 'src')
    ]
}
```

To:

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(process.cwd(), 'sass'),
      'node_modules',
      path.join(process.cwd(), 'src')
    ]
}
```

Notice the part on the `node_modules` you only need to remove `path.join` or any path resolution. I have been banging my head on this over the weekend and all I need is to change one line. (Typical Developer's life). By the way, it's not even this issue that points me to this solution. So things like  `can't resolve dom-helpers` and other Multiple library versions conflict with submodules, you need to check your webpack module resolution if your using webpack.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that sticks out to me is the fact that you configured babel with "commonjs" in the first preset. Try changing it to 'auto' or es6 modules.

The difference is that in commonjs you should import with `const a = require('some-module')`

And in es6 it's: `import a from 'some-module'`

You can test if this is the case by changing your import to:

`const Button = require('@material-ui/core/Button')`

or

`const Button = require('@material-ui/core/Button').default`

If it works, try removing the "modules" from the first preset or change it to "auto"
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#modules

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestions and I get the same error. So changing to this 

`const Button = require('@material-ui/core/Button')` wont work. I also updated my babel config to have the modules set to `auto`.

Comment: Can you share the code by uploading it to github maybe? I want to take a look at your package.json and try to build it myself

Comment: Hi, I can't upload the code. Sorry- But I can share the package.json. Also I tried replicating the issue by creating a new project with just the package.json, babel configs and webpack configs in it, and it works! So this really is puzzling.

Comment: I created a dummy project from scratch and copied all the configs including package.json. So webpack, babel and server render configs. Weirdly it works! Anyhow- I was already planning to re-write all my components and not to use material-ui but I'll keep this open until I could get some answer.

Comment: That's weird... Unfortunately I don't think you are going to get an answer without sharing the project. I hope you won't have this issue

Answer (score 0):

issue sorted after ugrading react and react-dom to 18